# Why is my PCI card denying network connections when installed?

Tags: networking, drivers, server

I have an older HP p6570y tower currently running Ubuntu Server 16.04 and functioning as a PleX server.  I bought a hauppauge WinTV-quadHD PCI card so I can start streaming and recording OTA broadcasts.

When I plug the card in it causes the machine to stop connecting to the network.  I normally see 3 types of network interfaces when I run `ifconfig`: `enp3so`, `lo`, and `virbr0`.  When I plug the new card it throws an error as it is booting and running through all the pass/fails regarding network interfaces being unable to be established. `ifconfig` will show only `lo` and `virbr0` as connections.

I ran through the install for the card located here: http://www.hauppauge.com/site/support/linux.html and had no problems.

Has anyone else run across this issue and found a good fix for it?  I shot an email to their tech support too but I doubt I hear anything prior to Monday.

Thanks

edit 1:  The only FAIL line reads as follows:

```
[Failed] Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

`ifconfig` still results in the same scenario as above.  It looks like the new card slot being occupied results in an Ethernet connection being denied.  I assume that maybe BIOS is calling the TV tuner card a network card?  Weird...

Output from the `lspci` command when run WITHOUT card installed:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS880 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (int gfx)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5)
00:11.0 RAID bus controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [Non-RAID5 mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 3c)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
04:06.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev c0)
```

the only differences that I see with the card installed is:

00:07.0 - PCIE port 3 - line is otherwise identical to 1/5

list remains the same through 02:00.0 from there it changes as follows:

```
03:00   PCI Bridge Device 2304
04:01.0 Same
04:02.0 Same
05:00.0 Multimedia video controller: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23887/8 PCIe Broadcast Audio and Video Decoder with 3D Comb (rev 04)
06:00.0 Same as 05
07:00.0 Ethernet Controller: same as 03 from without card installed
08:06.0 Firewire, same as 04 from pre-install
```

So the card being installed results in it being addressed prior to my ethernet card?  So does that mean that for whatever reason it isn't even looking for the card at that point?

Comment: I'd run `lspci` before and after inserting the TV tuner and compare the changes.

Comment: Perhaps a driver related issue?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly changes in the `lspci` output with out without the video card. Could you please [edit] your question to include the *complete, verbatim* output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0200]'` with an without it? Thanks.